# rails_admin won't let me keep my enum field as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

Model:

```rb
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  # https://naturaily.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-enum
  enum recurrence: {
    daily: 0,
    weekly: 1,
    monthly: 2,
    annually: 3
  }, _prefix: :recurring

  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, :user_id, presence: true
  ...
end
```

Migration:

```rb
class CreateReservations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :reservations do |t|
      t.string 'name', null: false
      ...
      t.boolean 'recurring', default: false, null: false
      t.integer 'recurrence', index: true, allow_blank: true, default: nil # trying a lot of things here
      t.datetime 'expire_time'
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Works as expected in the console:

```rb
2.4.5 :002 > res = Reservation.new(name: 'test', user_id: 1)
 => #<Reservation id: nil, name: "test", recurring: false, recurrence: nil, date: nil, start_time: nil, end_time: nil, expire_time: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

2.4.5 :003 > res.valid?
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => true

2.4.5 :004 > res.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Reservation Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "reservations" ("name", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "test"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2019-09-24 20:42:40.933959"], ["updated_at", "2019-09-24 20:42:40.933959"]]
   (2.1ms)  COMMIT
 => true

2.4.5 :005 > res.reload
  Reservation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Reservation id: 5, name: "test", recurring: false, recurrence: nil, date: nil, start_time: nil, end_time: nil, expire_time: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2019-09-24 20:42:40", updated_at: "2019-09-24 20:42:40"> 

2.4.5 :006 > res.recurrence
 => nil
```

And yet, in Rails Admin, when I create or edit a record, they all get assigned to the first enum. Even when I intentionally delete the value from the form, it still saves the record with the first enum value.

Rails Admin:

```rb
config.model Reservation do
    weight 2
    parent Event
    list do
      field :name
      field :display_date do
        formatted_value { bindings[:object].display_date }
      end
      field :recurrence, :active_record_enum # should be unnecessary, but trying everything
      field :expire_time
      field :user do
        label 'Creator'
        formatted_value { bindings[:object].user.name }
      end
    end
  end
```

I have tried:

- not indexing this field (thinking Rails Admin wants a value for indexed columns)

  ensuring `:active_record_enum` is declared on `field :recurrence`

As suggested, here's the related section of the log:

```rb
Started POST "/admin/reservation/new" for ::1 at 2019-09-25 10:09:50 -0400
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VbhHM7YD+oQvwMYIQzMHyT5e0MXFFuN3pyH/1s6yM8n6kqKvywZ5E8zaABMKhOU+oWpfU1Kk55FWYjL9TzbkbQ==", "reservation"=>{"name"=>"logs", "date"=>"", "start_time"=>"", "end_time"=>"", "recurring"=>"0", "recurrence"=>"", "expire_time"=>"", "start_time_of_day"=>"", "end_time_of_day"=>"", "day_of_week"=>"", "date_of_month"=>"", "date_of_year"=>"", "user_id"=>"1"}, "return_to"=>"http://localhost:3000/admin/reservation", "_save"=>"", "model_name"=>"reservation"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Reservation Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "reservations" ("name", "recurrence", "day_of_week", "date_of_month", "date_of_year", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "logs"], ["recurrence", 0], ["day_of_week", ""], ["date_of_month", ""], ["date_of_year", ""], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2019-09-25 14:09:50.926864"], ["updated_at", "2019-09-25 14:09:50.926864"]]
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/reservation
Completed 302 Found in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

And, sure enough the param `"recurrence"=>""` is transformed into `["recurrence", 0]`

It seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2993), but if it's a legit bug, I still need help with a work-around. Anyone solved this already?

Comment: What are the logs? The params being sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Logs confirm transformation of `""` into `0` as Ruby does: `"".to_i => 0`

Answer (score 1):

This technically works, but I'm thinking it's not the ideal solution:

If you declare your enum as a hash (not an array) and don't assign anything to 0, it works.

In my case `enum recurrence: { daily: 0, weekly: 1, monthly: 2, annually: 3 }` becomes `enum recurrence: { daily: 1, weekly: 2, monthly: 3, annually: 4 }`

The logs show the param isn't passed to the SQL:

```rb
Started POST "/admin/reservation/new" for ::1 at 2019-09-25 10:21:17 -0400
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Joyg5VuquwMMKg+ps2zg9t+8r0DZ0iOIkqRlk1cBkemJpkV5Jq84lO8wybL62wIBQIgg1k5gJ25j56i41oVGTQ==", "reservation"=>{"name"=>"test3", "date"=>"", "start_time"=>"", "end_time"=>"", "recurring"=>"0", "recurrence"=>"", "expire_time"=>"", "start_time_of_day"=>"", "end_time_of_day"=>"", "day_of_week"=>"", "date_of_month"=>"", "date_of_year"=>"", "user_id"=>"1"}, "return_to"=>"http://localhost:3000/admin/reservation", "_save"=>"", "model_name"=>"reservation"}
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Reservation Create (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "reservations" ("name", "day_of_week", "date_of_month", "date_of_year", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "test3"], ["day_of_week", ""], ["date_of_month", ""], ["date_of_year", ""], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2019-09-25 14:21:17.091292"], ["updated_at", "2019-09-25 14:21:17.091292"]]
   (5.7ms)  COMMIT
```

The param contains `"recurrence"=>""`, but the `INSERT INTO` doesn't have an array for `recurrence` like it did before.

And I confirmed in the console:

```rb
2.4.5 :001 > res = Reservation.first
  Reservation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations" ORDER BY "reservations"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Reservation id: 4, name: "test3", date: nil, start_time: nil, end_time: nil, recurring: false, recurrence: nil, expire_time: nil, start_time_of_day: nil, end_time_of_day: nil, day_of_week: "", date_of_month: "", date_of_year: "", user_id: 1, created_at: "2019-09-25 14:21:17", updated_at: "2019-09-25 14:21:17"> 
2.4.5 :002 > res.recurrence
 => nil
```

However, it seems to me like I'm just passing a dis-allowed value and letting Rails reject it. This still seems to be an issue with Rails Admin, specifically with integer enums.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a restriction of using hashes, because [nil values should work](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html#method-i-enum). Since you're mapping those to 0-indexed values, you should just use a symbol array. The ActiveRecord::Enum documentation (linked above) states:

> Note that when an array is used, the implicit mapping from the values to database integers is derived from the order the values appear in the array. In the example, :active is mapped to 0 as it's the first element, and :archived is mapped to 1. In general, the i-th element is mapped to i-1 in the database.

So you should be able to just use an array of symbols for this.

Comment: You are correct, but using a hash has some significant advantages for data integrity if I ever need to change the enum. See this article: https://naturaily.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-enum. It also proposes using strings instead of integers, but doing that breaks your schema file and makes testing a pain.

Comment: Also, I'm not having issues with nil values on the Ruby or Rails side of things, only in Rails Admin, my terminal code proves that. As much as I'd like to give you credit on this question, it's unfortunately not pointing at the right area.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the advantages, because you could simply rename the element at that specific index. Unless you anticipate eventually removing middling values entirely? If it's really important to you to use a specific integer, you could simply create an integer field and validate inclusion in the values of a frozen hash in your model. Or you could try something like Enumerize (https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) and see if that works for you. If it's only an issue with Rails Admin, I suggest filing an issue with the developer: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues